# Sanctum can't find personal_access_tokens table when using stancl multi-tenancy

Tags: laravel, oauth, laravel-sanctum

As i can see, everything is fine - the table exists and there is correct token for the user that is making a request when using stancl multi-tenancy. Also, when i make a request to the database from console, the response is correct, for example - "select * from "personal_access_tokens" where "token" = 'token symbols'" returns the row. But once i make a request to any api endpoint that require authentication ('auth:sanctum'), it returns following error: SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "personal_access_tokens" does not exist LINE 1: select * from "personal_access_tokens" where "token" = $1 i have no idea what does cause this, maybe somebody had the same problem?

Comment: This is likely to be related to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66261097/1091553]) and the tenancy not being initialized at the time Sanctum requests it (therefore the queries are run against your central database which gives you your table not found error).

Answer (score 0):

Type on terminal

```
sudo php artisan cache:clear
```