# Why InitializeTenancyByDomain is not applicable for the login process?

Tags: laravel, routes, middleware, multi-tenant

This is for Laravel 8.x with Jetstream/Livewire scaffold having Stancl/Tenancy. The initialization of tenant models or session settings not working right. Either I did not do it right or inbuilt problem.

The entire package was built as per instructions of Stencl/tenancy v3.x. I can see the dd(\App\User::all()) as per code outlined below

```
Route::middleware([ 
        'web',
        InitializeTenancyByDomain::class,
        PreventAccessFromCentralDomains::class,     
])->group(function (){
    
Route::get('/', function () { 
   dd(\App\User::all()); //can see all users models in tenants table
   return view('welcomeTenant'); 
});

Route::get('/home', [
    'middleware'  => ['auth'],
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index'
])->name('home');
                
});
```

This meant InitializeTenancyByDomain right to me.

When a login form is requested from tenant's domain eg. from rtbs.example.in, the encrypted session/cookie info is not stored in sessions table of tenant i.e. rtbs.sessions. When a login form is posted, it is looking for users in central domain (example.in) where users table is not present, hence the central.users table not exist error. As a result I get 419 error. I had disabled the csrf token verification temporarily to identify this problem.

This is the issue. Why the InitializeTenancyByDomain is not applicable for the login process? Could there be a fundamental setting wrong with me? Interestingly, the dd(\App\User::all()) if present anywhere else i.e. as show below

```
Route::middleware([ 
        'web',
        InitializeTenancyByDomain::class,
        PreventAccessFromCentralDomains::class,     
])->group(function (){
    
dd(\App\User::all()); //central-domain.users does not exist error

Route::get('/', function () { 
    return view('welcomeTenant'); 
});

Route::get('/home', [
    'middleware'  => ['auth'],
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index'
])->name('home');
                
});
```

The same sql exception i.e. central-domain.users table does not exist is thrown. Only when present inside the Route::get('/'... i can see the correct models.

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem with **Laravel Fortify**, which provides the backend to JetStream.  It only became a problem when I changed the session driver to database from file - though this will be  necessary for my deployment anyway.

The issue is that Fortify makes extensive use of dependency injection inside the constructor methods of their controllers.  As described in the [documentation for Tenancy](https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/early-identification), because of the lifecycle of a Laravel request the tenancy will not be available when these constructors run.  This means they will default to the central connection and cause failure to login.

Because we can't change the way Fortify uses constructors, the solution is to change the middleware to be global and add a check for central domains into the initialization middleware:

Copy *Stancl\Tenancy\Middleware\InitializeTenancyByDomain* to **App\Middleware\InitializeTenancyByDomain** changing:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    //Skip for central domains
    if(in_array($request->getHost(), config('tenancy.central_domains'), true)){
        return $next($request);
    }


    return $this->initializeTenancy(
        $request, $next, $request->getHost()
    );
}
```

**App/Http/Kernel**
use App\Http\Middleware\InitializeTenancyByDomain;

```
protected $middleware = [
    // ...
    InitializeTenancyByDomain::class,
];
```

**Config/fortify**

```
use Stancl\Tenancy\Middleware\PreventAccessFromCentralDomains;

'middleware' => [
    'web',
    PreventAccessFromCentralDomains::class,
],
```

**Routes/tenant**

```
Route::middleware([
        'web',
        PreventAccessFromCentralDomains::class,
    ])->group(function () {

        //Your Routes

    }
```

With this solution Fortify and Stancl Tenancy are now working well together with well separated databases, sesssions and logins.

Comment: I am getting Class 'Stancl\Tenancy\Resolvers\IdentificationMiddleware' not found any idea why that might be?

Comment: i still can't get session database to work. it still using landlord connection

Comment: @ZeroOne have you followed the documentation regarding [session scoping](https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/session-scoping)?  I use Redis for the session so I'm haven't used the file session driver

Comment: Yup.. i'm using custom session database.. so, i tried to override the getQuery() in DatabaseSessionHandler, change the connection there.. now its working.. i dont know why its not working by default

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work with Rory's answer. However, you need to set the correct namespace in `App\Http\Middleware\InitializeTenancyByDomain.php`:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware; // << use this instead of Stancl\Tenancy\Middleware

// [..]
use Stancl\Tenancy\Middleware\IdentificationMiddleware; // <<

class InitializeTenancyByDomain extends IdentificationMiddleware
```

Answer (score 0):

That package is very helpful, but it requires a **lot** of work to get all the pieces lined up and maintained. You've got the right middleware, including 'web' and the two tenancy bits, which will start the session and allow checks for CSRF.

I've had similar problems before.  The biggest cause for me was that it was not finding the right 'central' path, and thus not initializing tenancy correctly.

Make sure your **tenancy.php** config file is showing the right central domain.  Something like:

```
'central_domains' => [
     'example.in' // No http:// here
 ],
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. The central_domain is nothing but localhost (under assembly). Everywhere (by following the pipeline) the default db connection was to central_domain not that of the tenant. It makes the right query, and bindings but looking for wrong db. It is looking to query the table of central not that of the tenant. strangely, the dd(\App\User::all()) gives users of tenant only when it is present inside the Route::get('/'...If it is outside, again the same issue. Is it route maping/binding ?

Comment: I don't think it's route binding.  It just isn't initialising tenancy correctly, and this usually points to some config or another.  I'm sorry I can't help you here - I've had literally dozens of issues like this, and while the most common was the above, it ranged a bunch of different things.  With the complete refactor in V3, this became a *new* bunch of things, some of which we're still trying to track down.  One other thing that was common - make sure you don't have any routes duplicated between central and tenant.  IE make a different `/login` in web.php than in tenant.php route file.

Comment: Hi, i just made an attempt to do manual login using loginController and authenticate method. First time, i could see the entries in the tenant's sessions table where user_id number is present! Apparently, these tenant route have no middleware applied on them. This makes the laravel 8.x auth scaffolding more or less useless. The entire tenant portion needs to be manually applied on them or the restriction is only to auth middleware remains to be seen.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the old scaffold with L8, as it is an older project.  No idea why the need for an 'upgrade' there other than to make more work refactoring.

Comment: Finally I managed to crack the issue!  It is a long list of modifications!

Comment: When they changed the tenancy code to V3, I spent over 80 hours modifying to make it work like the older version.  What a waste of time.  I'm not a fan of 'upgrades' for the very reason that it costs me a fortune to support on our enterprise projects!

Answer (score 0):

Route's like next can issue bugs with database session store

```
Route::view('some')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a feature called `Universal Routes` check the documentation [here](https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/features/universal-routes)